# iOS app consuming multiple JSON with pagination

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am building an app and the API to be consumed by this app.

The app screen is something like this:

[image]

Static information are just basic information like name or job of the user.
Pagination are elements that will need pagination to charge new items.

Since it's a RESTful api,  I guess that the app must request 3 different calls here and then build the screen:

`/user/{id}`:

```
 {
    "data": {
       "name": "name",
       "birth_date": "birth_date",
       "bio": "bio"
    }
 }
```

`/user/{id}/community`:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "metadata": {
            "page": x,
            "per_page": x,
            "page_count": x,
            "total_count": x,
            "Links": [
                {"self": "/....."},
                {"first": "/....."},
                {"previous": "/....."},
                {"next": "/....."},
                {"last": "/....."},
            ]
        },
        "items": [
            ....
        ]
    }
}
```

`/user/{id}/post`:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "metadata": {
            "page": x,
            "per_page": x,
            "page_count": x,
            "total_count": x,
            "Links": [
                {"self": "/....."},
                {"first": "/....."},
                {"previous": "/....."},
                {"next": "/....."},
                {"last": "/....."},
            ]
        },
        "items": [
            ....
        ]
    }
}
```

If someone already manage to implement that kind of screen, is my concept the right one and some advice on how to merge all information.

Comment: Use tableview with multiple cells and put conditions.

Comment: so what's your problem!

Comment: Embed Collection View in `UITableViewCell` to design the interface. For the API calls its up to your requirements. If you want to show all at once, then wait until all calls are done then show with first page. Else create sections in table view and keep row count as `0` for data which is yet to be fetched. Once fetched from API response reload table view section. That should make it dynamic and not hold up UI for all calls.